# Adding time to a table in SQLplus without date

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a table regarding telecommunication and I want to add time for 2 rows `call_start_time` and `call_end_time` and with that, I want to calculate the call_duration.

This is what I used to enter the value

```
to_date('2021/05/31:20:20:20','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

If I use this format while displaying the data only the date is displayed not the time.

Can someone help me create a table where I just have to input the time alone not the date and calculate the call_duration using call_start_time and call_end_time?

Heres the table I created:

```
SQL> create table MOBILE_TRANSACTION (
                    mob_no number(10), 
                    call_type varchar2(25), 
                    call_category varchar2(25),
                    call_start_time date,
                    call_end_time date, 
                    call_duration number, 
                   call_charges_rs number );
```

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: sorry I meant to type sqlplus

Comment: Why not store the date *and* time - what's the advantage of not including the date? How will you handle a call starting before midnight and ending after midnight? (Or even spanning multiple days... don't suppose it happens much any more but used to with dial-up internet *8-) If you store date and time then the duration calculation is trivial.

Comment: If you're actually happy with how you're storing it now and are really asking about the "only the date is displayed not the time" part, then that's down to how your client is displaying the value, which may be via your session NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter. If you want to display the date (and time) as a string then you can format it with `to_char()` and the same format mask (though maybe without the extra colon you used).

Comment: A `call_start_time` must have a date and a time. The `DATE` data type in Oracle stores both date and time. It is displayed using a format. Refer to [Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-DFB23985-2943-4C6A-96DF-DF0F664CED96) in the Oracle database documentation.

Comment: Oracle doesn't have `time` datatype. If you do not want to develop string parsing and convoluted calculations, then use `date` datatype, which stores date and time, and take care of data display at the app side.

Comment: Hey, I am college student, we have a mini group project in DBMS and we got telecommunication topic. We couldn't calculate call_duration using the above format and it only displays the date and not time so, I thought it would be easy to calculate using just the time and not date. If you know how to find  call_duration using date and time then please help me with that.

Comment: Time of day with date is pretty useless.   Suppose you have 2 events: one at 04:00 AM and the other at  02:00 PM. Now which one occurred first? Well without the date you cannot tell, and since you cannot tell which was first how do you calculate the duration them.  See the comment by  Alex Poole to see why your date did not show the time. Run *alter session set nls_date_format='yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'  then rerun your to_date, and see the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TL;DR] You don't need to create a time column as the `DATE` column already has a time but SQL/Plus it not showing it; chage the settings on SQL/Plus and use what you already have.

---

Your table has a time component; the user interface (SQL/Plus) is chosing not to display it.

If you want to change the default display format then use:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   MOBILE_TRANSACTION;
```

If you want to explicitly convert the date to have a format (since it is stored as a binary value and has no format in the database and it is only when it reaches the user interface you are using that that user interface converts the binary to something human readable) then you can use `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
SELECT mob_no, 
       call_type, 
       call_category,
       TO_CHAR(call_start_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS call_start_time,
       TO_CHAR(call_end_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS call_end_time,
       call_duration, 
       call_charges_rs
FROM   MOBILE_TRANSACTION
```

---

If you want to calculate the duration then you can use a virtual column:

```sql
create table MOBILE_TRANSACTION (
  mob_no          number(10), 
  call_type       varchar2(25), 
  call_category   varchar2(25),
  call_start_time date,
  call_end_time   date, 
  call_duration   INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
                  GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
                    (call_end_time - call_start_time) DAY TO SECOND
                  ), 
  call_charges_rs number
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4b0172d7a41e2e737e945f1331b9a045)*

or

```sql
create table MOBILE_TRANSACTION (
  mob_no          number(10), 
  call_type       varchar2(25), 
  call_category   varchar2(25),
  call_start_time date,
  call_end_time   date, 
  call_duration   number
                  GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((call_end_time - call_start_time) * 24 * 60 * 60), 
  call_charges_rs number
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a6a20ee7be1ca42fe7a53b2d0252f143)*